# Json parsing gives nullpointer exception (android)

Tags: android, json, parsing

My first question here.
I'm a bit new to android and json aswell.

I have a .json file with some values in it (see below). I would need to parse it, i tried but i got a nullpointer exception. Any help would be great!

```
{
  "i": 475,
  "lp": "NEW",
  "c": "tlf",
  "dmc": 0,
  "hfg": false,
  "b": [
    "No",
    "Yes"
  ],
  "t": [
    {
      "i": 131321,
      "d": [
        {
          "d": "2014-07-01T08:32:08",
          "lm": 1,
          "s": 0,
          "b": 33,
          "i": 1,
          "sS": 63,
          "bV": 14.1,
          "h": 0.9,
          "mi": 137385101,
          "x": 0,
          "de": 0
        },
        {
          "d": "2014-07-01T08:39:08",
          "lm": 1,
          "s": 0,
          "b": 34,
          "i": 1,
          "sS": 63,
          "bV": 14.1,
          "h": 0.9,
          "mi": 137385102,
          "x": 0,
          "de": 0
        }
      ],
      "m": [
        {
          "a": 44.409315,
          "o": 26.204476,
          "b": 239,
          "f": 1,
          "i": 137385102
        },
        {
          "a": 44.409175,
          "o": 26.203828,
          "b": 255,
          "f": 2,
          "i": 137385103
        }
      ],
      "p": {
        "a": 0,
        "o": 0
      }
    }
  ],
  "e": [

  ]
}
```

Code:

```
 StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open(
                    "Chart-data-source.json")));
            String temp;
            while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null)
                sb.append(temp);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                br.close(); // stop reading
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        String myjsonstring = sb.toString();
```

Error:
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.chartdata.Main.onCreate(Main.java:47) - ( br.close(); this is line 47)

Comment: Post logcat output, your code, and mention which line gives error.

Comment: Provide code and logcat trace while posting.

Comment: Updated with code. thx

Comment: Pl also add the code which is giving error so one can see that and help you with. It is clearly visible that error is coming in Main.java oncreate method. so post that code

Answer (score 0):

To read a json from a file, try to use this method

```
    public static String readFile(String path, Charset encoding) 
          throws IOException 
        {
          byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
          return encoding.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(encoded)).toString();
     }
```

call the method like:

```
String myJsonString = readFile("C:/pathToJsonFile/folderjsonFlex.json", StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Then to create the json, just use

```
JSONObject myCoolJson = new JSONObject(myJsonString);
```